# Visual Studio does not propose libraries

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, reference, libraries, missing-data

Since a time ago my Visual Studio 2015, does not propose libraries to include (using) when i write classes from the framework. It only shows the error as follows:

> The type or namespace name "XXX" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image]

I think everything is ok in "References"

[image]

any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have  `using System.Net.Sockets` at the top of your code?  What happens if you press Alt-Shift-F10 with the caret on `TcpClient`?

Comment: Obviously this happens without manually adding the corresponding library. If i press Alt-Shift-F10 a popup shows "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3dfs6f5sd96fsd6ds' or one of its dependencies."

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it solved after removing component cache.

```
1. Close Visual Studio (ensure devenv.exe is not present in the Task Manager)
2. Delete the %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache directory
3. Restart Visual Studio.
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said but unfortunately it did not work for me.